# scroll to bottom not working on chrome browser in phone

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load more data as user gets to the bottom of the screen and i am using this condition .

```
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) === document.body.offsetHeight)
```

However this code is not working on chrome browser in chrome but works on web .What could be the reason behind.I know this is browser specific issue but how can we make it work on browser of all phones ?

Answer (score 2):

This "if" statement is working on my chrome on phone. You can check that your page in mobile version does not have any margins at the top or bottom, in the body element for example. If have, you need to remove that margins to it works.

Alternativelly you can try this statement:

```
if((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.scrollHeight)
```

If not works, you can add a little offset, like this:

```
if((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.scrollHeight - 2)
```